# Jquery keyup event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, keyup, onkeyup

I'm trying to create handle the `keyup` event in a search field in my page using JQuery. The event is not being fired however, I don't see anything in the console.

#### Relevant Javascript

```
$('input[type=search]').keyup(function () {
    var query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    console.log(query);
    $('li.file').each(function (index, element) {
        var name = $(element).text().toLowerCase();
        if (name.indexOf(query) >= 0) {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

#### Search Field

```
<li>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">&#128269;</span>
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: have you got an error in the console for your script ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis Nothing is being printed to the console

Comment: ok how do you create the script in a specific js ? (do you include correctly the js ?) directly on the page in the script tag ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis The script is inline at the bottom of the page.

Comment: ok so just to check if it's truly the event that is not raised. Could you try to add an id to your input and try adding the keyup handle by something like $('#youris').keyup(function ()

Comment: @jeremy-denis Adding the id and using it as the selector doesn't work either

Comment: ok thanks to have check. So it's truly the event. Do you have other event triggered or other javascript function that run in your page ? what i mean is all your javascript don't run or only this event ?

Comment: @jeremy-denis Only this event. Everything else works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i check your sample on my side all run find. try replacing your code by something like the following :

```
  $(function(){
    $('input[type=search]').keyup(function () {
        var query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        console.log(query);
        $('li.file').each(function (index, element) {
            var name = $(element).text().toLowerCase();
            if (name.indexOf(query) >= 0) {
                $(this).removeClass('hidden');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('hidden');
            }
        });
    });
    });
```

To be sure to call your function when the DOM is ready

Comment: Thanks that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a JQuery Version problem; below 1.7.0 .on() feature wasn't exist
You can try this working snippet;

```js
$('input[type=search]').keyup(function () {
    var query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    console.log(query);
    $('li.file').each(function (index, element) {
        var name = $(element).text().toLowerCase();
        if (name.indexOf(query) >= 0) {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search">
```

```js
$('input[type=search]').keyup(function () {
    var query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    console.log(query);
    $('li.file').each(function (index, element) {
        var name = $(element).text().toLowerCase();
        if (name.indexOf(query) >= 0) {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('hidden');
        }
    });
});


$('.modal-footer').on('click touchend', function () {
    $('#maximumTabsModal').modal('hide');
});

$('.file').on('click touchend', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
        return;
    var path = $(this).data('path').replace("\\\\", "http://" ).replace("PDFs","Uploads");
    var name = $(this).data('name');
    var lastname = $(this).data('lastname');
    name = name.length > 9 ?
        name.substring(0, 6) + '...' :
        name.substring(0, 9);
    lastname = lastname.length > 9 ?
        lastname.substring(0, 6) + '...' :
        lastname.substring(0, 9);
    var tabCount = $('#tabs li').size();
    $(this).attr('data-position', tabCount);
    if (tabCount === 0) {
        $('#toc').after('<div class="content"><ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="tabs"></ul><div class="tab-content"></div></div>');
    }
    if (tabCount === 5) {
        $('#maximumTabsModal').modal('show');
        $('.start-button').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('disabled')
        $('<li role="presentation" data-position="' + tabCount + '"><a href="#panel' + tabCount + '" aria-controls="panel"' + tabCount + ' role="tab" data-toggle="tab">' + name + '<span class="close"></span><br/>' + lastname + '</a></li>').appendTo('#tabs');
        $('<div class="tab-pane" id="panel' + tabCount + '"><div id="pdf' + tabCount + '" class="pdf"></div></div>').appendTo('.tab-content');
        $('#tabs a:last').tab('show');
        var options = {
            pdfOpenParams: {
                view: "FitV"
            },
            forcePDFJS: true,
            PDFJS_URL: "pdfjs/web/viewer.html"
        };
        var pdf = PDFObject.embed(path, '#pdf' + tabCount, options);
        $('#exd-logo').hide();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click touchend', 'span.close', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var tab = $(this).closest('li');
        var position = tab.data('position');
        tab.remove();
        $('#panel' + position).remove();
        $('#tabs a:last').tab('show');
        var tabCount = $('#tabs li').size();
        if (tabCount === 0) {
            $('.content').remove();
            $('#exd-logo').show();
            $('#get-started').show();
            $('#exd-logo').removeClass('inactive');
        }
        var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
        var position = $(parent).data('position');
        var file = $('li.file[data-position=' + position + ']').first();
        $(file).removeClass('disabled');
    });
    $(document).on('click touchend', '.tab-content', function () {
        var display = $('#toc').css('display');
        if (display === 'block') {
            $('ul#toc').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, "slow");
            $('.start-button').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">&#128269;</span>
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: The JQuery version I am using is 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery event is firing for me and it works fine. If this is what you wanted? :P
[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Are you including the jQuery file?

Comment: Yes, all of the other other code above that is using jquery works fine